# The best performance implementation of counting the number of true of an integer?

Tags: java

I have an integer number, and the number can be expressed in 32 bits. And I want to count the number of true values.

For example:
An integer 5566 can be expressed by `00000000 00000000 00010101 10111110`, the number of true values is 9.

The calculation should consider the performance because it's used for a large data set.

In java, it seems that I need to convert the integer into byte[] first, and then convert into a boolean[] and then start counting, and I think there is a better way with better performance and less conversion.

Comment: Are you talking about the number of one digits of the binary value? You can use 1 << n to check the nth bit.

Comment: Especially, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109054/10871900) mentioning `Integer.bitCount`.

Comment: @NomadMaker yes.

Comment: @dan1st Thank you! I'll check it.